# mvc after logout why ActionLinks are appear

Tags: asp.net-mvc

when i logout my user still Actioninks are visible.BUT after i refresh it its not visible
Please help me.

```
 public ActionResult LogOff()
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            return View("Index");
        }
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
 @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true && User.IsInRole("Admin"))
                {
     @Html.ActionLink("LogOut", "LogOff", "Home", new { area = "" })
     @Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Admin/AdminHome", new { area = "" })
```

Comment: Redirect to your `Index()` method - `return RedirectToAction("Index");` (not `return View("Index");`

Comment: `IsAuthenticated` may set to false after redirection (i.e. `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home")`. Just returning view still indicates current request is authenticated until next request.

Comment: @StephenMuecke ,yamamoto Thank u soo much  for your value ans